# Partial Posts in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am working on asp.net. and i want to implement partial posts in my application. my situation is like that
i dont want to url changed in address bar and even page should not refreshed at all.
for that i used script manager and update panel but still page refreshes and url also changes.

so any one have idea about it what to do?

Thank you

Comment: not sure what you want, but you can check out something like jQuery.get('page.html',function(result){jQuery('#yourDivId').html(result)},error_function)

Comment: do you have any example for this? or please tell me any link if you know

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Update panel and still your page is getting post back in that case check that `EnablePartialRendering` should be true. If this is not the case then check your configuration and all the handlers as registered properly for AJAX.

I will suggest you to use jQuery instead of update panel for partial page post back. Do a google and you will find lot of example on this.

Check this [ASP.NET postback with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751415/asp-net-postback-with-jquery)

Comment: Do you know any link for it becoz i also tried out for jquery but still its not working.

Comment: Please check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751415/asp-net-postback-with-jquery