# How to retrieve HTML control values which are placed in contentPlaceHolder in code behind file?

Tags: c#, html, master-pages, contentplaceholder

I've designed a web site. In that web site I used master page for my web page . And in that web page I've placed HTML controls which are in the content place holder. I want to retrieve values of the HTML control in the code behind file. How to do this?

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <div>
   <span>
       <select id="Select1">
           <option value="1">Low</option>
            <option value="2">Medium</option>
             <option value="3">High</option>
              <option value="4">Not Assigned</option>
       </select></span>
       <span>
           <input id="Text1" type="text" /></span>
       <span>
           <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
           onclick="Button1_Click" />
           </span>
   </div>
</asp:Content>
```

I want to retrieve the HTML control value on the click event of the `Button1`.

Comment: you should add your code here!! It's help us to understand your problem.

Comment: check this out.. a simillar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389149/how-to-access-html-form-input-from-asp-net-code-behind

Comment: @karthi: yes i worked on that question. But it is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Mark them as `runat="server"` on the aspx page and give them an ID and you should see them in the code behind

****Edit****
You can alternatively just use an ajax call either via web method or do a seperate postback to send only the data you want if you are worried about performance.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751415/asp-net-postback-with-jquery) article.

Comment: I don't want to make html control as server control.

Comment: Then you won't be able to see it in the code behind? That is the only way of seeing it in the code behind. Why don't you want to make it a server control?

Comment: I think , If i make my html control as server control then it'll take some time for rendering the web page as compare to the html control.

Comment: And when we use server control then at the time of rendering all the server control are converted into html control.

Comment: I would suggest setting them as runat server and see how it affects your performance. Normally this is negligible and this might be a case of micro optimizing your code too much?

Comment: The other option would be to use Jquery to do an ajax postback to your page, but again this is hacky code and I would suggest to try and avoid it as much as possible. I do suggest however you look into asp.net mvc as it seems it might server your needs better if you are starting on a new project

Answer (score 0):

As TBohnen.jnr says, you can mark them as runat="server".

If you don't want to do that then you can use Request.Form["idOfInput"], but that's not generally recommended when using WebForms.

Comment: I've tried this too. But it is not working. It's giving null value.