# jquery postback failing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to initiate a postback invoking the click function of a server-running element, as to run some C# code, in the event of a particular jquery dialog button click.

I am using a modal dialog with buttons as per [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) jQuery UI example.  I have attempted using all of the different answers for javascript/jquery postback invocations in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751415/asp-net-postback-with-jquery) question.

I've set a couple of breakpoints in my C# code to see if these postbacks are getting called, but nothing is getting hit.

I have this dummy element in my ascx file to use:

```
<a id="anchorId" runat="server" onclick="return true;" onserverclick="TryLogin"></a>
```

I've attempted to get this postback to occur a few different ways:

```
$("#anchorId").click(); //just simply does nothing
document.getElementById("anchorId").click(); //This one gives me a null javascript error
$("document").getElementById("#anchorId").click(); //tells me [object] doesn't have a getElementById
__doPostBack('<%=anchorId.UniqueID %>', '');//Also does nothing in the jQuery code, but works in standard javascript code
```

Lastly I did try retrieving the unique ID in the code behind as:

```
string id = anchorId.UniqueID;
```

and replaced in the javascript this way:

```
__doPostBack('Softening_Main$anchorId', '');//Still does nothing, and no javascript error
```

I really need some help here, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of issues in your code.

`$("document")` will not select `document` instead will look for `document` tag element on the page. You should use `$(document)` removing the quotes.

Also `getElementById` is a JavaScript method of `document` object which is used to find element by id. When you use `getElementById` don't specify `#` in the id. `#` is used by jQuyer to differentiate between various selectors.

Remove inline `onclick="return true;"` from anchor and try this.

```
$("#anchorId").click(function(e){
    __doPostBack('<%=anchorId.UniqueID %>', '');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: `Asp.Net` generates a `UniqueID` which is the control's name appended with all naming containers seperated by colon, it is same as `ClientID`(id attribute of the control) which uses underscore as seperator.

Comment: @DanF - Where do you place this code? Do you see any error on the page?

Comment: I do not get any errors on the page or in my javascript console.  in my ascx file I import a scripts file `<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.scripts.js"></script> ` and in that file I have the dialog code:  `$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 150,
  width: 350,
  modal: true,
  buttons: 
  {
   "Login": function() 
   {
    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    $("#anchorId").click(function(e)
    {
     __doPostBack('<%=anchorId.UniqueID %>', '');
     return false;
    });
    return true;
   },...`

Comment: Since this code is in a js file it is not working. Can you render anchors UniqueID in a variable from your main and and use that variable in this code.

Comment: You mean replace `'<&=anchorId.UniqueID %>'` with its actual unique id gotten in the code behind?  I did try that as well but that didn't work either

Comment: Did you put the actual uniqueid that gets generated by asp.net?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7809/discussion-between-dan-f-and-shankarsangoli)